# access private object variable from public method

Tags: javascript

How can I access `ctx` in the function `loadImage`? I have seen snippets that worked exactly like this but It just doesn't work when I try it. It always says 'this' or 'this.ctx' or 'ctx' is undefined.

```
var MyClass= function(canvasId){
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
};
MyClass.prototype.loadImage = function(imageSrc){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;
    //cannot access this or ctx
    image.onload = function(){
        this.ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    };
    //can't even access it here:
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

};
//window.onload = function(){
 var myObject= new MyClass("myCanvas");
 myObject.loadImage('myImage.jpg');
```

Comment: You can't access `ctx` in `loadImage` unless you were to move the definition for `loadImage` into the function definition of `MyClass`, or declare `ctx` outside of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can access `ctx` from proptotype methods is to set it as an instance property using `this` keyword.

```
var MyClass = function (canvasId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
};

MyClass.prototype.loadImage = function (imageSrc) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var self = this;
    image.onload = function () {
        self.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };

    this.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
```

Note that inside image `onload` handler you have different context: `this` no longer points to `MyClass` instance, but rather to image object instance. You can overcome it for example by saving a reference to proper `this` in some variable like `self`.

Comment: usage* not declaration :P

Comment: @crush: It could (should?) have been `var canvas` still

Comment: This answer makes `ctx` public visibility now, by the way. Bergi's is the only real solution besides moving the var into a closure outside of the class "ctor".

Comment: Thanks your answer! You said `this.ctx` makes `ctx` an instance property. Does that mean that `var ctx` will be an static property that is the same for every instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: No, `var` would make just local scope variable which will not be available outside.

Comment: @flawr `var ctx` would be local to the function, whereas `this.ctx` is assigned to the instance.

Comment: Static property would be `MyClass.ctx` which is not what you want, because you probably want to have different canvases and ctx's per MyClass instances.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand, thank you very much for answering (so fast!) I didn't expect to get overrun with answers so quickly!!!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access ctx in the function loadImage?

You cannot. Unless you create the `loadImage` function inside the constructor's scope. See [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572) for details.

> I have seen snippets that worked exactly like this

Then those snippets didn't work either.

Comment: What other structure of the program would you recommend, if you want to have multiple methods accessing `ctx`?

Comment: I would recommend Bergi's structure...using `this.loadImage = function() {}` inside of your function ctor. Your other option is to wrap everything in a closure, and move `ctx` outside of the function ctor, but then `ctx` becomes "shared".

Comment: Thank you very much, that explained a lot!

Comment: @crush Also putting `ctx` as prototype property would have the same effect. But having shared `ctx` is probably not ideal at all. As I can see that there can be different canvases, hence different 2d contexts.

Comment: I've also seen some libraries use naming convention as a method of restricting visibility, though, it depends on the knowledge and restraint of the developer to enforce. For example, they'd do `this._ctx` where the `_` denotes that `ctx` is meant to be private scope. This kind of programming is generally a code smell in my opinion. I'd highly recommend that you DON'T follow that practice.